# How do I add an item to a ListView from another thread without causing an exception

Tags: c#, multithreading

I try to add a row to a listView

```
listView1.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] { item1 });
```

from a different thread to the one in which it was created and it throws an Exception.

Can anyone help me understand how to do this correctly?

Comment: The topic title should be relevant to your question

Comment: This should **not** be closed.

Comment: @Lazarus: I almost walk all over your edit. Great minds and all that :)

Comment: @Justin - You are correct. Did they take away the ability to remove your vote to close?

Comment: @Justin(2) You never had the ability to remove your vote-to-close if I remember correctly.

Comment: @Binary, serves him right!  He completely clobbered mine!! `:P`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`Control.Invoke()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) to execute your code back on the UI thread:

```
listView1.Invoke(
    new MethodInvoker(delegate(){ 
        listView1.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] { item1 };
);
```

Comment: Using the generic type 'System.Action<T>' requires 1 type arguments

Comment: What version of .NET and C# are you using. Also, is that code snippet your actual code...or was that simply an example?

Comment: @rebel_UA: The non-generic `Action` delegate is only available in framework 3.5 and later. Just declare a parameterless delegate that you can use instead: `public delegate void InvokeAction();`.

Comment: @Guffa @rebel_UA - Modified my answer a bit to not use the Action delegate.